# How to handle downloads in QWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, download

I know that QWebEngineProfile and QWebEngineDownloadItem are used in order to download something. But I don't understand how. I'm trying to use connects in order to achieve downloads. Here's my code

```
void MainWindow::handleDownloadSlot(QWebEngineDownloadItem *download) {
    download->accept();
}
void MainWindow::downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem *download) {
    download->accept();
}
  connect (pro,SIGNAL(downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem *)),this,SLOT(handleDownloadSlot(QWebEngineDownloadItem *)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Web Demo Browser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-demobrowser-example.html) example which includes an example with a Download Manager.

If you are sharing a default [QWebEngineProfile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html), try:

```
    connect(QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile(), SIGNAL(downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem*)),
                this, SLOT(downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem*)));
```

For a profile defined in a custom [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html), try:

```
    connect(webView->page()->profile(), SIGNAL(downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem*)),
                this, SLOT(downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem*)));
```

Now handle your download to start:

```
void MainWindow::downloadRequested(QWebEngineDownloadItem* download) {
        if (download->savePageFormat() != QWebEngineDownloadItem::UnknownSaveFormat)  {
            qDebug() << "Format: " <<  download->savePageFormat();
            qDebug() << "Path: " << download->path();
            // If you want to modify something like the default path or the format
            download->setSavePageFormat(...);
            download->setPath(...);
            // Check your url to accept/reject the download
            download->accept();
        }
}
```

If you want to show a progress dialog with the download progress, just use signals availables in the class `QWebEngineDownloadItem`:

```
connect(download, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(setCurrentProgress(qint64, qint64)));
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. I click download button and nothing happens. It doesn't even show anything in debug console

Comment: I'm porting from QWebKit to QWebEngine. And there was signal called linkClicked. There's no such signal in WebEngine. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: The code is working for me in Qt 5.7. If you want to handle every single URL, check my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343790/how-to-use-qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor/38351234#38351234

Comment: For python i just did `QWebEngineView().page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(downloadFucntion)` and then accepted it by `downloadItem.accept()` . Hope it's helpful ^

Comment: @Pixsa >3 years later: would love to know how you got the download to work in Python! Trying to get it to work in https://github.com/MadsAndreasen/PySideFlask and failing - do you have any boilerplate or more detail? Would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: @JonT sorry mate, I don't remember anything about this project

Comment: @Pixsa got the code in your old comment to work so all is good :)