# How to use QWebEngine to intercept HTML requests?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

In `QtWebKit` we can use `QNetworkAccessManager`, like：

```
class NetworkAccessManager : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
public:
    explicit NetworkAccessManager(QNetworkAccessManager *manager, QObject *parent);
protected:
    QNetworkReply * createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation,const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *device);
};
```

We can implement `QNetworkReply * createRequest()`. In this method we can get:

1. operation (`QNetworkAccessManager::Operation operation`)
2. request (`const QNetworkRequest &request`)
3. some data (`QIODevice *device`)

From request we can get the url, from "some data" we can get some data from html (I don't know how to call “some data”, so I call "some data").

In `QtWebEngine` we can use `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` to get operation and url, like:

```
class WebUrlRequestInterceptor : public QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
{
public:
    WebUrlRequestInterceptor(QObject *p = Q_NULLPTR);
    void interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info);
    ~WebUrlRequestInterceptor();
};
```

We can implement  `interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info)`, in this method we have info, from info we can get

1. operation (`info.requestMethod`)
2. url (`info.requestUrl`)

Now I want to get "some data", how can I get it?

Comment: Using QWebEngine to intercept request the above question is related to this previous question asked on StackOverflow. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343790/how-to-use-qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343790/how-to-use-qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor)